# "Clip vector layer by mask layer" algorithm stucked in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, masking

I am using QGIS 3.22 and I try to use a mask to get rid of the part of the shapefile I don't want. However it stays stucked (see img) without even pointing an error.

Does someone know what to do? I try to use intersections but this returns me invalid geometries and with the clipping part it comes back with an error...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to try

Set an actual file output path, as opposed to a temporary output. I've noticed sometimes some of the processing tools will bail when attempting to write the temporary output.

Also, try performing it on a very very small area first (ie: Make a dummy mask file)

Additionally, based on your description here, you are wanting to clip your shapefile, but if I am reading correctly, it looks like you have set the shapefile as the mask layer.

Comment: Yes because I notice that when I do intersection it returns me invalid geometries but not with mask and clip...the buffer eventually worked but it is extremely long... Thank you a lot for your answer!

Comment: nr_aus, when I save the clipped layer on a permanent file, I still have a output super poor (I am loosing all the invalid geometries...)

Comment: ok might I suggest we break the issues down into a few different posts. This current post was specifically about the algorithm being 'stuck'. If setting an output file has resolved the 'stuck' issue, then we can consider this issue fixed, so lets close this one off. And i recommend you raise a new post with new question about the new problem (or perhaps research first for others whom may have had that issue).

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to invalid geometries in the original layer.

You can try using your mask layer for a spatial query (in QGIS "Select by Location") to select all the features from the orignal layer, that are within your mask. Then export the original layer to a new file and select the option "Save only selected features" in the export dialog.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot but it still does not work... the algo runs and then no files is appearing, maybe I did not chose the right tool? I selected "intersect" in the fourth option under "select a feature from" and "creating a new selection"

Comment: The "Select by Location"-Function only selects certain features in your orignial layer. It does not create a new file itself. You should select "intersect" as well as "are within" and "contain". You should also make sure, that you have entered the correct layers for input and selection mask. You have to save the selected features as described above afterwards.